# What is a product $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, intuition

My question is relatively simple: what is a product $\sigma$-algebra? And why they are important?

Can anyone suggest any links of intuitive (possibly with simple figures) explanations? Or, maybe someone can explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are important because they are necessary for the most correct statements of the [Tonelli and Fubini theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

I'm not sure there is a natural way of thinking about it. Do you have an intuition for how open sets in $X \times Y$ look when you know what basic open sets in $X$ and $Y$ look like? Even though basic open sets in $X \times Y$ are "rectangles", there can still be "open disks" in $X \times Y$.

The situation for $\sigma$-algebras is similar, but even uglier. That is the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb E \otimes \mathbb F$ on $X \times Y$ when $(X,\mathbb E)$ and $(Y,\mathbb F)$ are measurable spaces is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\{A \times B \subseteq X\times Y \mathrel| A \in\mathbb E,\thinspace B \in \mathbb F\}$.

Comment: Can we say that the product $\sigma$-algebras are analogue of product topology?

Comment: @Ninja Yes. The basis which generates a product topology has the exact same appearance as the set which generates a product sigma algebra.